# Is there a built-in menu functionality in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, contextmenu, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing an app with phonegap and I'd like to have an action menu, that is similar to the menus of other apps on the OS and without actually developing a menu myself.

I just want to provide the menu items(and/or icons) and the functions when they are selected.

Is there something in phonegap or any plugin that does this?
Is there even such a thing as a common menu in Android and IOS?

Something like the following for android :
[image: Android action menu in an app]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not certain whether there is anything for this in the Cordova eco system, but i readily use jQuery Mobile in my Cordova apps. Could be overkill for your needs (if this is the only one), but works well for me with complex UX designs).

Comment: JQuery Mobile or Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. Feared something like this.
Strange though. It's very rare to find an app without a context menu and it pretty much forces you to use a framework.

Comment: I think you'll find (as you develop your app) that you'll need more than just a menu, and a framework will give you most (if not all) of what you need

Comment: @quikin, I'm developing it for some time now and there's a lot more than just a menu that I need. I didn't say I'm not using a framework. That's not the point. 

I want a menu that is provided by the OS. I want the same look and feel. I want it to update with the OS version. I don't want the menu design to be dependent on a framework or to design it myself.